# why if I enter a negative number in the method, condition else if does not catch it

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, sequence, negative-number

I have problem with solution in this example.

```
Input:>6 
Output:0+1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21 

Input:> -15 
Output:-15<0  

Input:>0  
Output:0=0
```

```
public static string ShowSequence(int n)
{
    int sumInt = 0;
    string sum = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            sum += i + "=";
        }
        else if (n < 0)
        {
            sum += n + "<";
        }
        else
       if (i == n)
        {
            sum += i + " = ";
        }
        else
            sum += i + "+";
        sumInt += i;
    }
    sum += sumInt;
    return sum;
}
```

Everything works except a negative number , because my program return 0 not -15<0. Thanks for help !

Comment: Your Loop Condition  `i <= n;` fails before the start of first iteration when the number is negative. For this reason, the execution never reaches the if/else conditions.

Comment: This is because when you give a negative number as an input, your for loop will never execute

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` ---> `for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Abs(n); i++)`

Comment: What about add validation for negative numbers before for loop?

Comment: @npinti That's going to print the `-n<` message n number of times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check your input in the loop, and that's where it goes wrong.
I modified your code, and pulled the check out of the for-loop, and returned early to avoid confusion.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLmo62

```
public static string ShowSequence(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return n + "=";
        }

        if (n < 0)
        {
            return n + "<";
        }

        int sumInt = 0;
        string sum = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (i == n)
            {
                sum += i + " = ";
            }
            else
            {
                sum += i + "+";
            }

            sumInt += i;
        }

        sum += sumInt;
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Loop Condition `i <= n;` fails before the start of first iteration when the number is negative. For this reason, the execution never reaches the if/else conditions.

You could rewrite the method with condition checks prior to entering the loop.

```
public static string ShowSequence(int n)
{
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return n + "=";
        }

        if (n < 0)
        {
            return n + "<";
        }

        int sumInt = 0;
        StringBuilder sum = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            sum.Append($"{i}{(i==n?" = ":"+")}");
            sumInt += i;
        }
        sum.Append(sumInt);
        return sum.ToString();
}
```

Please note I have also used [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder), instead of strings. The string class is immutable, which means that each time you append/modify a `string`, you are essentially creating a new `string` object in memory. In situation like the case in hand, where the `string` is repeatedly modified, you should avoid the overhead of creating `string` for every modification. For this purpose, you could use the `StringBuilder` class.

As an additional note, you could further reduce the code by making use of Linq. For example,

```
public static string ShowSequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return n + "=";
    }

    if (n < 0)
    {
        return n + "<";
    }

    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.Append(Enumerable.Range(0, n+1)
                               .Select(x => x.ToString())
                               .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "+" + b));
    strBuilder.Append($" = {(n*(n+1))/2}");
    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply state the special case: `n == 0`, `n < 0.
Then use [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) to generate all number from 0 to n.
And [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__), without the "Is that the last elements? Do I need one more + ?".
And [Enumerable.Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8) to compute the sum.

You will end up with a really straight forward code.

```
public static string ShowSequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return n + " = 0";
    }

    if (n < 0)
    {
        return n + " < 0";
    }

    // generate all numbers from 0 to n. Takes n+1 steps. 
    var enumeration = Enumerable.Range(0, n+1);

    var plusOperatorConcatenation = String.Join(" + ",  enumeration ) ;

    return plusOperatorConcatenation + " = " + enumeration.Sum();
}
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iu0vyf